# extract sub-string from long text

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string as:

```
string="
(2021-07-04 11:58:43 PM BST)  
---  
le  ) says tosen
```

Hi yohan

```
(2021-07-05 12:04:42 AM BST)  
---  
len (Trade ) says to sen  
okay -5 / 0  .



(2021-07-04 11:47:14 PM BST)  
---  
Keun says to
HanSo 
hello 
  
  
  
  
--- 


  
  

(2021-07-05 12:09:41 AM BST)  
---  
len (Trade) says to sen  
yes -5 / 0 TN -- / +2.5  
  
  
---  
  
* * *

Processe | 2021-07-05 12:26:44 AM
BST  
---

"
```

All I want to extract the text after `says to` and before `timestamp`.

Expected output as:

> text=['yoh Hi yo','sen   okay -5 / 0 ','sen yes -5 / 0 TN -- / +2.5']

What I have tried:

> text=re.findall(r'says to (\D+)(',string)

Answer (score 1):

There are digits in between `says to` and the next timestamp between parenthesis, so using `\D+` will stop matching when there is a digit.

Instead you can capture want you want after matching `says to` in group 1 for all following lines that do not start for example with `(` and a digit or `---` (or make it more specific)

```
\bsays to (.*(?:\n(?!\(\d|---).*?)*?)\s*\n(?:\(\d|---)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/reayan/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pZx7Jc)

For example:

```
pattern = r"\bsays to (.*(?:\n(?!\(\d|---).*?)*?)\s*\n(?:\(\d|---)"
text = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(text)
```

Output

```
['yohan sen  \n[[:Conversations will be recorded and may be monitored by the participants and\ntheir employers:]] Hi yohan', 'yohan sen  \nokay -5 / 0', 'yohan sen  \nyes -5 / 0 TN -- / +2.5']
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. Just one more doubt as `says to` in string could also have possible variation as I have edited in question (name can also be in next line). Could you please help how to deal with '\n' in that case?

Comment: @new_learner Do you mean like this with a word boundary instead of a space? `\bsays to\b(.*(?:\n(?!\(\d|---).*?)*?)\s*\n(?:\(\d|---)` See https://regex101.com/r/2iILa4/1